# How can I restart the border colors of VSCode? Suddenly they changed

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

[image]

So today I opened my VSCode and it looks like the screenshot.

I didn't apply any changes to it. I just turn off my computer last night and today these are the colors. I already changed the theme and still the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It happens that before installing the peacock extension, it affects the VSCode workspace, to solve it:

- You must download and install `peacock` again
- Once installed you must open the extension options `ctrl + shift + p` on windows
- Finally, click on the option `Reset workspace color`
  [image: illustrative image]

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and find the Peacock plugin, and change the preferences, un select Affect Title Bar , and sync the changes with previous.

This worked for me...... if anyone else having the issue